# FFMPEG No such filter: 'palettegen'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, video-conversion

I am using windows 10 and FFmpeg 64-bit Shared Version.

When I use palettegen effect, returns error.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf palettegen palette.png
```

returns

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0228d3c0] No such filter: 'palettegen'
Error opening filters!
```

How can I install this Filter? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's recent version. I download it from here [link](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/shared/) ffmpeg-latest-win64-shared.7z

Comment: Can you run `ffmpeg` in the command line and post the output please?

Comment: @aergistal here output I uploaded it, [link](http://prntscr.com/9bda6e)

Comment: That is definitely not a recent version. As you can see it's from 2013. The filter in question was added this year.

Comment: i download it from official website. how can this be possible? I deleted ffmpeg folder and PATH but it's still running. Where is this oldest version folder?

Comment: Did you check both User and System PATH environment variables?

Comment: I found it! I installed ImageMagick before, this oldest version came it in. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to move my answer from comment to post.

The problem is about ImageMagick. ImageMagick was installed  in my computer, this oldest version was in it.